# Segmentation fault in recursive backtracking maze generator C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to create a maze generator using recursive backtracking and have come across a problem that I just can't get my head around. For some reason my move function is returning the value "18446744073709551615". This is (of course) leading to a segmentation fault. Why is my move function returning such a large value when my move function can only increase or decrease the value by 2?

```
bool maze::generate(size_t x, size_t y) {

//mark the position as visited
labyrinth.s[y][x] = true;

//print to see progress
//this->print();

//if the position is not out of bounds
if (x < 0 || x > labyrinth.MAXWIDTH - 1 || y < 0 || y > labyrinth.MAXHIGHT - 1) {
//if the position is the endpoint return true
if (labyrinth.v[y][x - 1] == 'W' || labyrinth.v[y][x + 1] == 'W' || labyrinth.v[y - 1][x] == 'W' || labyrinth.v[y + 1][x] == 'W') {
  return true;
 }
}

//pick a random direction
do {
  d = size_t(rand() % 4);
} while(!this->pos_test(x, y, d));
std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;

if (d == UP) {
y = move(x, y, UP);
}
else if (d == DOWN) {
y = move(x, y, DOWN);
}
else if (d == RIGHT) {
x = move(x, y, RIGHT);
}
else if (d == LEFT) {
x = move(x, y, LEFT);
}
else{
}
std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
//recursively generate the maze
if (this->generate(x, y)) {
  return true;
}
}

void maze::initialize(size_t x, size_t y) {
   //set the maxhight and the maxwidth to y and x
   labyrinth.MAXHIGHT = y;
   labyrinth.MAXWIDTH = x;
   //set all elements in the vector to #
   for (size_t i = 0; i < labyrinth.MAXHIGHT; i++) {
     std::vector<char> temp;
     for (size_t j = 0; j < labyrinth.MAXWIDTH; j++) {
       temp.push_back(labyrinth.wall);
     }
     labyrinth.v.push_back(temp);
   }
   for (size_t i = 0; i < labyrinth.MAXHIGHT; i++) {
     for (size_t j = 0; j < labyrinth.MAXWIDTH; j++) {
       if (j % 2 == 1 && i % 2 == 1 && j != labyrinth.MAXWIDTH - 1 && j != 0 && i != labyrinth.MAXHIGHT - 1 && i != 0) {
         labyrinth.v[j][i] = labyrinth.path;
       }
     }
   }
     //set all posistions to unvisited
     for (size_t i = 0; i < labyrinth.MAXHIGHT; i++) {
       std::vector<bool> temp2;
       for (size_t j = 0; j < labyrinth.MAXWIDTH; j++) {
         temp2.push_back(false);
       }
       labyrinth.s.push_back(temp2);
    }
     //setup the start point
     labyrinth.v[0][1] = 'S';
     //setup the endpoint
     labyrinth.v[labyrinth.MAXHIGHT - 2][labyrinth.MAXWIDTH - 1] = 'W';

  }

  //if a position has been visited or if not possible to go to return true
 bool maze::pos_test(size_t x, size_t y, size_t d) const {
    //if the position is out of bounds return false
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > labyrinth.MAXWIDTH - 1 || y > labyrinth.MAXHIGHT - 1) {
       return true;
   }
    else if (x == 1 && d == LEFT) {
      return true;
   }
    else if (y == 1 && d == UP) {
      return true;
   }
   else if (x == labyrinth.MAXWIDTH - 1 && d == RIGHT) {
     return true;
   }
   else if (y == labyrinth.MAXHIGHT - 1 && d == DOWN) {
     return true;
   }
   else if (d == UP) {
     return labyrinth.s[y - 2][x];
   }
   else if (d == DOWN) {
     return labyrinth.s[y + 2][x];
   }
   else if (d == RIGHT) {
     return labyrinth.s[y][x + 2];
   }
   else if (d == LEFT) {
     return labyrinth.s[y][x - 2];
   }
   else  {
     return true;
   }
 }


size_t maze::move(size_t x, size_t y, size_t d) {
//if the position is out of bounds return without modifying
if (x < 0 || x > labyrinth.MAXWIDTH - 1) {
  return x;
}
else if (y < 0 || y > labyrinth.MAXHIGHT - 1) {
  return y;
}
else if (d == UP) {
  labyrinth.v[y - 1][x] = labyrinth.path;
  return y =  y - 2;
}
else  if (d == DOWN) {
  labyrinth.v[y + 1][x] = labyrinth.path;
  return y = y + 2;
}
else if (d == RIGHT) {
  labyrinth.v[y][x + 1] = labyrinth.path;
  return x = x + 2;
}
else if (d == LEFT) {
  labyrinth.v[y][x - 1] = labyrinth.path;
  return x = x - 2;
}
else  {
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: *Why is my move function returning such a large value when my move function can only increase or decrease the value by 2* -- What debugging have you done?  I think its time to use the debugger that comes with your compiler toolset.

Comment: your move function does not return anything within the last `else`. It could be that the huge number you see as return value is just some garbage value. Turn on your compilers warning, fix that and do some debugging

Comment: @tobi303: It's actually -1 underflowing because `size_t` is unsigned.

Comment: And for the persons suggesting debuggers: I would normally agree, and the OP should definitely learn how to use debuggers in case they don't know already, but I'm afraid that without understanding how things can underflow, the values displayed in the debugger wouldn't make much sense to the OP either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are underflowing your unsigned 64-bit return type `size_t`.

You are checking whether `x` and `y` are below zero, but that's not enough, because 0 and 1 will still be too low because you are subtracting 2!

The number you get is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in hexadecimal. This is the highest possible value for an unsigned 64-bit integer.

It comes from calculating `1 - 2`. Yes, this is supposed to be `-1`, but because your move function doesn't return a *signed* number but an *unsigned* one (check the docs on `size_t`), it can't be negative! [Instead, it wraps around to the highest possible number.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

You can imagine this in the same way you would get ...99999999999 when you try to calculate 1 - 2 on paper ignoring the "you can't subtract a higher number from a smaller one on paper" rule.

As a side note: I guess the negative result is undesired anyway, because actually your huge number, once added to a pointer, will in turn *overflow* back into positive, so basically it will work the same is a real `-1` in your case and the segmentation fault comes from accessing something *right before* the beginning of your buffer, not far beyond it, but it comes down to the same thing.

Apart from that, there is no need to do `return y = y - 2` and such. Just `return y - 2`.